# How do I chomp off everything after a character?

Tags: perl

I want to create a Perl program to take in a file, and for each line, chomp off everything after a certain character (let's say a /).  For example, consider this example file:

```
foo1/thing 1.1.1 bar
foo2/item 2.3.2 bar
foo3/thing 3.4.5 bar
```

I want to remove everything after the slash on each line and print it out, so that that file becomes:

```
foo1
foo2
foo3
```

I tried to use this program, with `readline` in a `foreach` loop, but the output was not what I expected:

```perl
print ( "Enter file name: " ) ;
my $filename = <> ;
$/ = ''
chomp $filename ;

my $file = undef ;
open ( $file, "< :encoding(UTF-8)", $filename
$/ = '/' ;
foreach ( <$file> ) {
    chomp ;
    print ;
}
```

But all this does is remove the slashes from each line.

```
foo1thing 1.1.1 bar
foo2item 2.3.2 bar
foo3thing 3.4.5 bar
```

How can I alter this to produce the output I need?

Comment: Remove everything on each line after the first or last such character?

Comment: The first slash.

Comment: Use of `$/` won't do what you need. That variable sets what is considered to be end-of-record, a "newline" so to speak. Whatever it's set to is used by operators such as `readline` (aka `<>`) and `chomp` as the marker for end of "line."  So `<>` reads up to the first such character and returns that as "line" (in scalar context), then again ... you end up not removing _anything_ other than just those characters themselves (`/` here).   When you say "_remove everything after the slash on each line_" you mean line in the "normal" (usual) sense; then you don't want to redefine what a "line" is.

Comment: Consider a file containing characters `abX\nX12X`.  Open it, set `$/ = 'X';`, and read with `while (<$fh>)`.  The `readline` (`<>`) will read three "lines" (`abX`, `\nX`, `12X`), and if you also use `chomp` on each those `X` will be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as concerns, the input record separator (`$/`) does not allow regexes.

You could proceed as follows:

```
print ( "Enter file name: " ) ;
my $filename = <> ;
chomp $filename ;

open ( my $file, "< :encoding(UTF-8)", $filename ) 
    or die "could not open file $filename: $!";
while ( my $line = <$file> ) {
    $line =~ s{/.*}{}s;
    print "$line\n";
}
```

Regexp `s{/.*}{}s` matches on the first slash and everything afterwards, and suppresses it (along with the trailing new line).

Note: always check for errors when using `open()`, as noted in [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

> When opening a file, it's seldom a good idea to continue if the request failed, so `open` is frequently used with `die`.

Comment: This didn't work.  It produced the same result as before.

Comment: @Blue-ManedHawk did you get rid of the `$/` stuff?

Comment: Yay, it worked!  Thank you!

So why did I need to remove that stuff?

Comment: because that was making it consider `/` to be the end of a line instead of a newline character, so whatever came after was the start of the next line and not affected by the substitution

Answer (score 3):

```
$line =~ s{/.*}{}s;                       # In-place (destructive)
```

or

```
my ($extracted) = $line =~ m{([^/]*)};    # Returns (non-destructive)
```